# How to call this homomorphism-like property?

Tags: terminology

In my communication theory work I derived a property that is essentially
\begin{align}
f(x)\cdot f(y) = f(x-y) \cdot A^N 
\end{align}
where $A^N$ is some quantity from the technical context that is obviously preventing $f$ from being a homomorphism.

What would be a good term to call this property of $f$? I could only come up with the unsatisfying 'homomorphism-like property'.

Comment: Pseudo-homomorphism? Or you could take the approach of the category theory people and call it a scalomorphism or some other kind of mumblemorphism.

Comment: Thanks. Pseudo-homomorphism sounds good, I'll stick with that. Scalomorphism seems to be inappropriate and an extremely uncommon term (Google).

Comment: That's because I just made it up.  The category theory approach is to invent a new term for each kind of morphism.

Comment: If you write $g=A^{-N}f$, then $g(x)g(y) = f(x)f(y)A^{-2N}=f(x-y)A^NA^{-2N}=g(x-y)$. So really, $f$ is a rescaling of a homomorphism.